# checking the size of graphic drawing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, 2d

```
 public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
 g.setColor(Color.red);
 g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
 g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
}
```

This method draws the oval with x=2, y=2,width=10,height=10. **How can i get the size of the drawing painted ?**

Comment: by output stream do you mean System.out? it's confusing because you say "painted".

Comment: The `drawOval()` call is redundant unless painted a different color to the `fillOval()`.  Most of the rest of the question reads like nonsense.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260821/ending-the-balls-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I get the size of the drawing painted?

Once it's painted, that information becomes part of the component's graphics context. There's no easy way to retrieve it without examining the pixels. Instead, treat the oval's size as constant, and use it in your calculation as shown [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html).

Comment: @ trashgod with reference to the link: what is `height-1` and `width-1` ?

Comment: Typically, coordinates are numbered from zero. The rightmost coordinate is then `x + width - 1`, and the bottommost coordinate is `y + height - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming width and height are instance variables.
All you need to do in a JComponent is set the top left corner of the oval for the X and Y *relative to the JComponent's top left corner*, then set the size of the oval with a proportion of getWidth() and getHeight().